# Python-OpenCV detecting player coordinates using minimap compared to fullsize map

Tags: python, image, opencv, matching

So, I am trying to use pythons OpenCV library to detect player coordinates in a video game by matching the minimap image to the full-size game map.
for testing, I've pared down the full-size map to something smaller.

I'm pretty new to both Python and the OpenCV library, so please forgive my ignorance.

I started by converting my images to grayscale, I resized my minimap image to be the same scale as the large image (so that the features can match exactly, I was hoping)
I used Canny edge detection on both since the maps use lots of white lines for walls, and figured this would help simplify everything. I did also try without doing this but it was no better.

my issue is honestly just finding an accurate match, I get matches all over the full-size world map and nothing specific. here is my code:

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

COORDS = [0,0]

WORLD_MAP = cv2.imread('world_map_gray.png')
#WORLD_MAP = cv2.cvtColor(WORLD_MAP,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
WORLD_MAP = cv2.Canny(WORLD_MAP,200,255)
#WORLD_MAP = cv2.Laplacian(WORLD_MAP,cv2.CV_8U)

MINI_MAP = cv2.imread('screenshot.png')
MINI_MAP = MINI_MAP[110:315,1540:1767]
MINI_MAP = cv2.cvtColor(MINI_MAP,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
MINI_MAP = cv2.resize(MINI_MAP,(87,79),interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
MINI_MAP = cv2.Canny(MINI_MAP,200,255)
#MINI_MAP = cv2.Laplacian(MINI_MAP,cv2.CV_8U)

#resize to 87,79

########COPY FROM WEB####################################################
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = WORLD_MAP          # queryImage
img2 = MINI_MAP # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.SIFT_create(sigma=1)

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 10)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []

for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.5*n.distance:
        good.append(m)


#good = sorted(good,key = lambda x:x.distance)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RHO,2)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h,w = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
    COORDS = [np.abs(dst[0][0][0]),np.abs(dst[0][0][1])]
    COORDS[0] = COORDS[0] +img2.shape[0]/2
    COORDS[1] = COORDS[1] +img2.shape[1]/2
    


    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
    print ("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                   flags = 2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)


WORLD_MAP_KP_IMG = cv2.drawKeypoints(img1,kp1,None)
cv2.imwrite('results\\WORLD_MAP_KEYPOINTS.png',WORLD_MAP_KP_IMG)

MINI_MAP_KP_IMG = cv2.drawKeypoints(img2,kp1,None)
cv2.imwrite('results\\MINI_MAP_KEYPOINTS.png',MINI_MAP_KP_IMG)


cv2.imwrite('results\\MATCHES.png',img3)
print("COMPLETE")
print("COORDS: ("+str(COORDS[0])+","+str(COORDS[1])+")")
```

here are the results, the Mini-map with its keypoints on it:
[image: Mini-map keypoints]

[image: WorldMap with keypoints]

[image: Matches]

and of course, here is where the actual location of it is:
[image: Location of the potential match]

As far as I can tell there just aren't enough key points in the minimap image to match with - but I'm not sure how to remedy this.
I've been reading through websites and documentation all day, I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

--EDIT

as requested here are the raw source images:

[image: WorldMap]

[image: MiniMap]

Comment: Please do not post links. Instead please include them as images or text inside the question. Links can broken over time.

Comment: @JoeFerndz New users aren't allowed to post images directly in their questions, only links. And imgur is the service used by Stack Overflow for posting images, so they're probably not going anywhere. It seems to me that the OP has done everything correctly.  Perhaps, now that you have the reputation to make edits to posts, you could format the image links to make them appear inline.

Comment: please don't run sift on a canny'd picture. canny destroys information. please don't use it here.

Comment: please post the original unfiltered pictures as data people can work with

Comment: run samples/python/find_obj.py (in opencv source/repo) and see if that works for you

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I gave that a go, I get an error with SURF, but the other ones run without errors.
I tested every combination, tried with and without FLANN, tried coloured, or grayscale images, tried some light blurring or gaussian blurring, but I can't get any good matches...

Any idea why? is it since my sample image is so much smaller than my image I'm searching in?

Comment: it would be best if you could post unfiltered unaltered unresized data

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: My guess is that @ChristophRackwitz is correct and you are losing too much information. There are simply not enough interest points on your minimap. If you take a look at the result it recognizes "cliffs" corrrectly but it can't do much more than that. I can imagine that it would work correctly if you didn't lose trees, rocks and other small features - especially rocks because you are literally in a mine.